# Calculating maximum likelihood ratio using hypotheis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots,X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with pdf $\frac{1}{\sigma} e^{-\frac{(x − \mu)}{\sigma}}$ for $x > \mu$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are both unknown, $-∞ < μ < ∞$, $0 < σ < ∞$; and  $n ≥ 2$. Derive the ML estimators for $μ/ σ$ and $μ + σ$.

I am able to find the maximum likelihood estimator for $μ$ and $σ$ which is ML for $μ = X(1)$  (smallest order statistics)  and ML for $σ = (X_i – X(1) )/n$. What does ML for  $μ/σ$ mean? should we have to calculate ML for $μ$ and $σ$ separately? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify here: 1/σ*exp[-(x − μ)/ σ] x > μ? Why do you have an inequality in your pdf?

Comment: The acutal pdf function is pdf 1/σ*exp[-(x − μ)/ σ], given  x > μ. sorry i am do not have any idea more than this

Comment: I already edited your post. Try tu use LaTeX for your math expressions next time.

Comment: Appreciated. I am the novice user

Comment: Search for 'invariance property' of MLE.

Comment: @dlnB Actually the pdf is $\theta(x-\mu)\frac{1}{\sigma} e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}}$, where $\theta(\cdot)$ is the unit step function. Alternatively, one can define an exponential distribution as an exponential for $x\ge\mu$ and zero for $x<\mu$.

Comment: However, there is a problem with this, as usually $\mu$ is reserved for the mean, or expected value and in this case, it is not. In this case, $\mu$ is a location parameter, and the more simple version of the exponential distribution has no location parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your log-likelihood is

$$ \ell(\mu,\sigma)=-n\log \sigma - \frac{1}{\sigma}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu) $$

so the MLE of $\sigma$ is $\hat{\sigma} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)$. By equivariance of the MLE, $\hat{\sigma} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \hat{\mu})$. In fact what you have is a shifted Exponential distribution, so once you shift it again, you recover the MLE of the $\lambda$ parameter of $Exp\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)$.

Comment: I could not understand you last line. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: I don't know what part of the last line you are referring to, so I'll walk through. I found the MLE by simply maximising the $\ell$ with respect to $\sigma$. Equivariance states that if $g:\Theta \to \Theta'$ is a bijection and $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE of $\theta$, then $g(\hat{\theta})$ is the MLE of $\theta$. Finally I say that your problem is easier by noting that $Z:=X-\mu$ has a distribution $Z\sim Exp\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}\right)$ and the MLE of $\sigma$ (or $\lambda$ in the usual notation) is well-known.

Comment: .Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
L(\mu,\sigma) & = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( \frac 1 \sigma e^{-(x_i-\mu)/\sigma} \right) \\[8pt]
& = \frac 1 {\sigma^n} e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)/\sigma}.
\end{align}
**As $\mu$ increases, $L(\mu,\sigma)$ increases *until* $\mu$ gets as big as $\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}.$** Therefore the MLE of $\mu$ is $\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}.$ So we have
\begin{align}
L(\min,\sigma) & = \frac 1 {\sigma^n} e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \min)/\sigma} \\[8pt]
\ell(\min,\sigma) = \log L(\min,\sigma) & = -n\log\sigma - \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \min)/\sigma. \\[8pt]
\frac\partial{\partial\sigma} \ell(\min,\sigma) & = - \frac n\sigma + \frac 1 {\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\min) \\[8pt]
& = \frac{-n\sigma + (\text{the sum above})}{\sigma^2} \qquad \begin{cases} >0 & \text{if } 0<\sigma< \text{sum}/n, \\ =0 & \text{if } \sigma= \text{sum}/n, \\ <0 & \text{if } \sigma > \text{sum}/n. \end{cases}
\end{align}
So the MLE for $\sigma$ is $\displaystyle \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i - \min\{x_1, \ldots, x_n \} \right).$

Then the **equivariance** of MLEs says that the MLE for $\mu/\sigma$ is
$$
\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\} \left/ \left( \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\} \right)\right. . \tag 1
$$

Alternatively, we can let $\alpha = \dfrac\mu\sigma$ and then we have this density for each observation:
$$
f(x) = \frac 1 \sigma e^{-(x/\sigma) + \alpha} \quad \text{for } x\ge\alpha\sigma.
$$
Then find the MLE for $(\alpha,\sigma).$ The MLE for $\alpha$ will be what you see in line $(1)$ above.

Comment: Thank you. what principle lies behind the postive, negative and zero value assign to the partial with respect to σ .In the next question MLE for μ+σ, is it ok to add two ML of μ and σ?

Comment: @DglPr : A function increases on intervals where its derivative is positive and decreases on intervals where its derivative is negative. $\qquad$

Comment: @DglPr : You can add the MLEs of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to get the MLE of $\mu+\sigma$ because that is what equivariance of MLEs says.

Comment: Apprecited.Thank you for your time and effort for the clarification.